# Firebase Dynamic Link won't open App Store

Tags: react-native, app-store, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using Firebase Dynamic Links for Android and iOS.

I've successfully configured the links for Android - open app if installed and Play Store if not.

For iOS, the app will successfully open if the app is installed but if it isn't the user does not get directed to the App Store. Instead they are presented with a page in the browser stating "Open link in app?".

I've configured my project in the Firebase Console to include App Store ID and Team ID. I've confirmed my dynamic link domain has an Apple app site association file for my app at [my domain]/apple-app-site-association.

Any ideas as to why when my app is not installed the dynamic link will not redirect to the App Store?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve through the redirects in `firebase.json` and custom URL can be add the app URL under the dynamic link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how do you build your dynamic url, but if you use the rest api, you should set app store id: ios.setAppStoreId('123456789')

```
const linkParams = firebase.dynamicLinks().newDynamicLinkParameters('https://invertase.io', 'https://xyz.page.link');
linkParams
  .ios.setBundleId('io.invertase.testing')
  .ios.setAppStoreId('123456789')
  .ios.setMinimumVersion('18');

 const link = await firebase.dynamicLinks().buildLink({
   link: 'https://invertase.io',
   domainUriPrefix: 'https://xyz.page.link',
   ios: {
     bundleId: 'io.invertase.testing',
     appStoreId: '123456789',
     minimumVersion: '18',
   }
 });
```

My guess is since the url to app store looks like this: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id**1505798107** you need to provide the appStoreId as well.

check: https://rnfirebase.io/reference/dynamic-links/dynamiclinkiosparameters

Answer (score 0):

[image: Firebase Console]

Firebase Dynamic Links provides default dynamic links as follows:

**Long Dynamic Link:**
https://preview.page.link/?link=https://example.com//&apn=com.example.package&isi=123456789&ibi=com.example.package

**Short Dynamic Link:**
https://preview.page.link/linkpreview

Above both links will redirect you to App Preview Page on iOS devices.

[image]

You can **bypass or skip the App Preview Page** by specifying the dynamic link parameter **efr=1**.

And now your Dynamic Link URL will look like

https://preview.page.link/?link=https://example.com/&apn=com.example.package&isi=123456789&ibi=com.example.package&efr=1

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/link-previews#app_preview_pages